# Script to upload CV with cookie control

Tags: php, jquery, html, form

I have created a script which presents a popup on every 5th pageview.

I would like to try to use just PHP cookies. However, due to the requirement of setting them before any content is output, it has made it tricky.

I would also like to just include this script and have it run. At the moment I believe the breaks are stopping the rest of the page/content underneath rendering. Standalone, however, works great.

Anyway, it's pretty ugly, and I was wondering if I could have some feedback.

```
<?php 


    if($_POST['noDelay'] === 'true'){
        $showPopups = '3';
    }else if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        popUp();
    }else if($_COOKIE['submitCv'] === '2'){
        $showPopups = '0';
    }else{
        $showPopups = '1';
    } 



    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
        case 'domain1.com':
            $border = '#FB7E12';
            $background = '-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E25704, #FB7E12 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent';
            break;
        case 'domain2.com':
            $border = '#651727';
            $background = '-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #651727, #651727 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent';
            break;
        case 'domain3.com':
            $border = '#0099CA';
            $background = '-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #0099CA, #0099CA 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent';
            break;

?>


<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width : 650px) {

        h4{color: #FB7E12;font-size: 2em;}
        #uploadCv{font-size: 20px;}
        #uploadCv input{ padding: 2.5px; display: block; height: 30px; margin: 20px 0;}
        #buttons{width: 264px; margin: 20px auto;}

        #popup form label{ display: inline;float: left;width: 150px;}
        #popupBlack{ height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); z-index: 100; top: 0; left: 0;}
        #buttons input{height: auto;margin: 0 10px;}

       input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, button:hover, .button:hover {
            background: <?php echo $background; ?>;
            border: <?php echo $border; ?>;
        }
        input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button, .button {
            border: 1px solid #FB7E12;
            background: #FB7E12;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #FFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 1em;
            float: left;
            min-width: 100px;
            margin: 0 16px;
        }



        #popupWrap{position: fixed; top: 50%; margin-top: -200px;/* half of #popup height*/
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 101;
        }

        #popup{
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            height: 400px;
            border:1px solid black; 
            padding:0 20px;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 101;
        }
    }
</style>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


//update the function below, give the close button a different ID to the return.

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#popupBlack, #closePopup").click(function(){
        $("#popupBlack, #popup").hide();
        document.cookie="submitCv=1;path=/";
    });

    $("#closePopupPerm").click(function(){
        $("#popupBlack, #popup").hide();
        document.cookie="submitCv=2;path=/";
    });

});


</script>
```

```
    <div id="popupBlack"></div>
    <div id="popupWrap">
        <div id="popup">
            <h4>Upload your cv now</h4>
            <form action="uploadCvContained.php?showPopup" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="uploadCv">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])){echo $_POST['firstName'];} ?>" required autofocus/>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastName'])){echo $_POST['lastName'];} ?>" required />
                <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Email'])){echo $_POST['Email'];} ?>" required />
                    <input type="hidden" name="noDelay" value="true" />
                    <input type="file" name="attachment"  required style="margin:0;height:auto;"/>
                    <p style="font-size:0.8em;padding:0;margin:0;">Accepted file types: pdf, doc, docx, rtf, txt and rtx</p>
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" id="closePopup" />
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <div id="popupBlack"></div>
    <div id="popupWrap">
        <div id="popup">
            <h4>Error</h4>
            <p>The file doesnt meet the upload criteria, please try again</p>
            <form action="uploadCvContained.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Return" id="returnPopup"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstName'];?>" /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastName'];?>" /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $_POST['Email'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="noDelay" value="true" />
            </form>
            <script>document.cookie = "submitCv=0;max-age=60000000;path=/"</script>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
    header("Location:".$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]);
    return; 
}?>


<?php

    $firstName = ucwords(preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $_POST['firstName'] ));
        $lastName = ucwords(preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $_POST['lastName'] ));
    $customerEmail = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $_POST['Email'] );

    $customerDetails = $firstName." ".$lastName."\r\n".$customerEmail;


function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

    $file  = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];

    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "Bcc: bcc@domain2.com" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        //echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here

        // show completed/sucess form
        ?> 
        <div id="popupBlack"></div>
        <div id="popupWrap">
            <div id="popup">
                <h4>Thank you for submitting your CV<?php echo $sendMailTo;?></h4>
                <p>We will add it to our DB. Next why not, sign up to alerts, or start a job search.</p>
                <input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Close" id="closePopupPerm"/>

                <script>document.cookie = "submitCv=2;max-age=60000000;path=/"</script>

            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

            } else {
                echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
            }
        }
    }

    $my_file = $fileName;
    $my_path = "$uploadedImagePath";
    $my_name = "Company Name";
    $my_mail = "info@domain1.com";
    $my_replyto = "info@domain1.com";
    $my_subject = "New CV attached";
    $my_message = "Hello,\r\nA new CV has been submitted.\r\n\r\nCandidate details:\r\n".$customerDetails."\r\n\r\n";
    mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, $sendMailTo, $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);



 }


if($showPopups === '3'){ showPopup(); }

if($showPopups === '1'){ ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout(
          function() 
          {
                    $('#popupFrame').slideToggle();
          }, 1000);

});
    </script>


    <div id="popupFrame" style="display:none;">
        <?php showPopup(); ?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reflected XSS via POST**

Echoing user input unsanitized is a really bad idea. [XSS is also possible via POST](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42466/reflected-xss-attack-via-post-request-and-xml-payload), and thus an attacker could steal your cookies, display phishing forms on your website, log all keystrokes, and so on.

So when echoing user data, always [protect against XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

**Misc**

- you mix HTML and PHP too much. For example `mail_attachment` should only mail the attachment. The success/error HTML should be somewhere else, along with all the other HTML.
- along that note: a function should only do one thing. Your `mail_attachment` function reads from a file, sends a mail, echoes something to the user and displays HTML.
- `$showPopups` isn't a good name, as it doesn't tell me what it does.
- your indentation is off, which makes your code hard to read (eg it looks as if `mail_attachment` was called recursively).
- naming consistency: sometimes, you use camelCase, sometimes snake_case and sometimes alllowercase (which is really hard to read). It's better to choose one and stick with it.
- also, it's easier to read code if equal things have equal names. eg `$my_file` vs `$fileName`, `$my_path` vs `$uploadedImagePath`, etc.
- in theory, it might be possible to [inject into the body of an email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342165) (I didn't test this).